# Angular routing 'Refused to load the font '...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy'

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have a problem with routing. Here are the routes I configured:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/products/all', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'products/:category', component: ProductsComponent}
]
```

If I start the page from '', then the ProductsComponent gets showed successfully, but if I load the website directly from 'products/all', then I get an error like this:

```html
Refused to load the font 'data:application/font-woff2;base64,d09GMgABAAAAAQ5sABIAAAADuOQAAQ4EAAEAgwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG4SpIhy4XhSHMgZgAJJmCF4JgnMREAqGskiFyggSgrVoATYCJAOdOAuOXgAEIAWPGAfGYAyDGFsKfLME/nOMvX+HnQoMqyRqK6tt2TW8K2BDX9Umu4PZkCXwtMjpcHYNTx6UUmu30UdwcxxnVMvcNgAim7rdXiPZ////////////C5dF2ObuXM7ZvQeSECARwueHlaLVtkJEIaLRAI3ulswSE13cSPdM15RCyYQuuS7A0mBqpQO9pYZWQQMqa9lQb0dpJzHxHpLyCHIi8uBdwF58nNH+YOA40OpJvEjJtaokKaUkx/N5UeSinp5TWoW1vSpFjimBgeFGeCF66U0n6ZUN/qSqC4XC11GKUNmzSy2d5Jxyqw5JzGUlJUnyi0lKkE8BlxadTZsyRm8c1/Cti2hEjzIH...FVw9csGnQ1BnbMbfzgRj3WjPytwZYWpPh3OtmsLZaNcxxqaGVqMVqFffFpU8bbs/0N1vG3POWfS7LUeB81TfHn+VbD7x/UnT3lXyFltHfdX6+X6Rzmg9d4dAISK7GlTj2zgME/JUwAETAECwABAUgUmAysrKI5shRwAchnFSMheQ8UoKlvnVbkW9mMeq2+bbO9EQ2q09Z9wzsADarYt4ftoamBDi8gmfbZKnl+lkZWyRx1VYVSIpVFXs9VXy9ytCyTNYt09YIAGKjqpDT22SgOdP5OsdAK/vOCXFnrpEwA/PPTJiopB7HxZV+MlaGCT/04K/LY3kjPYV/YR146Ggg+9sX6na/c2So+Epz3PXve3PKRylPIhNZASBUYVDIGhikiWc1jj/claeVCJvljX7JfvO+xhfTDIjSXBs4HV16Ol/BMfcuFQ4NRmDOWEh6diOI6NZmGl87N9J+r2JfpW2+5NhV/fGHLO57Yavbq7zaCewa/RDxp/aSH+luOPwAA' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

After seeing other posts here, I tried to add some Content Security Policy directive, but the error is still there and the website doesn't show at all.

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
```

Thank you!

Comment: But products/all should just use /products/:category, doesn't it?

Comment: Well, if I navigate to the empty URL '', then I will be redirected to '/products/all' where all is for the :category in the '/products/:category' configured route. So in the backend I take the category variable in order to display only the products from a certain category. All this will be displayed in ProductsComponent.

Comment: I am using Chrome.

Comment: I don't have Grammarly extension and it does not work with the meta tag... I check the IP and the port.

Comment: Same problem in Mozzile, but I do get a print on the screen "Cannot GET /products/all"

Comment: I do not load any specific font, I am just using Bootstrap but I don't think this affects.

Comment: It doesn't work if I add that path, it behaves like it does without it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to your case is defining multiple routes.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService]},
  {path: 'products/:category', component: ProductsComponent},
  {path: '', component: ProductsComponent}
]
```

And check for parameter and do your further logic:

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    if (params['category'])
  });
}
```

Your case is having an optional parameter and the above solution should work.